# Android studio generate APK get error Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug'

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I get this error:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process /Users/mohammad/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/2a8ecf8990ef0fa0c976a742db5c3bdc/jars/classes.jar
```

What did I do?

1- remove caches folder.

2- upgrade gradle

3- restart android studio

4- add android.enableD8=true

5- add -dontwarn and -keep

6- remove com.google.android.gms:play-services

How can I fix this problem?!

Comment: Run with `./gradlew --stacktrace`, you might get more information on what is happening

Comment: @gtxtreme I get this error but I can't find anything about it: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'CoreFoundation': Native library (darwin/libCoreFoundation.dylib) not found in resource path (/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/lib/bootstrap.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/lib/extensions.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/lib/util.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/lib/jdom.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/lib/log4j.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/lib/trove4j.jar:/Applications/Android

Comment: Looks like a macbook related issue